# Is 24 number is even or odd?

Tags: php

I am working on my test case for checking if number is odd or even and when I number is 3 then it shows Odd number but number is 24 then it still shows number as Odd number.

I am using modules Divide for checking the Odd Even number. Please have a Look at the code and let me know where I am making mistake:

```
<?php



$stdin = fopen("php://stdin", "r");

fscanf($stdin, "%d\n", $N);

fclose($stdin);

if($stdin / 2 != 0){

print("Weird");
}
else{

    if(($stdin >= 2) && ($stdin <= 5)){
        print("Not Weird");
    }
    elseif(($stdin >= 6) && ($stdin <= 20)){
        print("Weird");
    }
    elseif($stdin > 20){
        print("Not Weird");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your check is wrong. `/` gives you a quotient and you need to check for a remainder using `%`.

Comment: `echo 24 / 2`; is easiest, definitely not `0`.

Answer (score 0):

use module operator `%` instead of division

https://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.mod.php

24 / 2  = 12 So it will not be 0

24 % 2  = 0 since it calculates remainder  ( what is left over when division has been done equally )

23 % 2 = 1 (since after dividing equally we will have 1 left

Comment: Sorry about "/" I am using % but still that is not working